# AJAX function syntax - I don't understand well

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have combined many examples I found on various sites (including this one) and created the following HTML code that includes the needed AJAX function.

I added this to my head tag (this stopped one of the page errors I was getting):

```
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The rest of my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(function () 
        {
            //var vInvoiceNo=document.getElementById('idInvoiceNo').value;
            $.ajax({
                url:'InvoiceViewFunction.php', //where is the SQL
                data: "InvoiceNo=209",  //value SQL needs to run the WHERE -- This will eventually be a variable I get from the form
                dataType: 'json',      
                success: function(data) //the data that returns from SQL
                {
                    //Populating variables
                    var vInvoiceNo = data[0];
                    var vClientName = data[2];
                    //Update form content
                    $('#idName').html(vClientName); //the idName is an input field on my html form
                } 
            });
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<form action="InvoiceViewFunction.php" method="post">
<?php include("InvoiceForm.php"); ?> <!--content of the html form with tables, tr, td etc-->
    <button class="Button" type="button">Get Invoice with AJAX function</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

There are no errors when I load the page but nothing comes back when I click the button.  I don't quite understand what I am doing.  I wrote comments of what I do understand. I do not have enough "function" knowledge to troubleshoot it.  This is a function zoo with all the function inside a function business.  Help!

This is the code from InvoiceViewFunction.php:

```
<?php
//Connect to database
include("../ConfigFiles/ConnectDB_local_i.php");

    //Populating the variables
    $InvoiceNo = $_POST["nInvoiceNo"];

    //Reading a specific invoice from DB
        echo "<br>Trying to read from DB with invoice = <br>" . $InvoiceNo . "<br>"; //This tells the correct number just fine.
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `invoicedata_table` WHERE InvoiceNo = '$InvoiceNo'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        //if($result->num_rows > 0) 
        //{
        //  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        //  {echo stripslashes($row['ClientName']) . "<br>";}
        //}
        //else 
        //{echo 'NO RESULTS';}
        echo json_encode($result);



//Close the DB connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: SQL query from a form, huhuhu...

Comment: try putting data as `data: { "InvoiceNo":"209" },`

Comment: Can you post the PHP file too?

Answer (score 0):

The data syntax is wrong.
It should be:

```
data: {"InvoiceNo":209};
```

***EDIT# 1***

On another note, did you `json_decode()` the data on the server side?

***EDIT# 2***

Also, are you getting any errors on your console?

Comment: data can be serialized, so it should work the way it is in the example

Comment: Eisa Adil, I tried the new data version --- data: {"InvoiceNo":209}, --- and there is no change in the behavior.  I do not know what json_decode() means.  I edited my question to include the php code that has the SQL in it.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You have no element with `id="idName"`, therefore the result isn't put anywhere.</del> Derp. Read the comments!

If it's an input element, then what you are effectively doing is:

```
<input id="idName">blah blah blah</input>
```

Obviously, this is invalid!

Try `.val(vClientName)` instead.

Comment: @EisaAdil Considering the code given contains the entire `<body>` element, I doubt it.

Comment: No, because he has also included the `("InvoiceForm.php")` file there.

Comment: Eisa Adil, my input field comes in via the InvoiceForm.php.  I tried the .val(vClientName) and there is no change.  No errors on page or return from the function.

Answer (score -1):

You're using the "document ready" jQuery function rather than simply calling `$.ajax`. Omit the enclosing `$(function() { })` and just call `$.ajax` from within the click event handler.

Here's more information on "document ready" syntax: http://www.faridesign.net/2012/03/shorthand-for-jquery-document-ready-event/

Comment: Eisa Adil is correct, as well. The data property should be a JavaScript object.